# Power BI Conditional formatting for Matrix background Column name

Tags: powerbi, report, dax, reporting

I have these data in power bi

```
Status  Cat Values
Amber   Cat1    9
Green   Cat1    4
Blue    Cat1    3
Amber   Cat1    5
Amber   Cat1    3
Green   Cat2    2
Green   Cat2    2
Blue    Cat2    8
```

I produce a report to see the summary using Matrix Visual

[image]

i want to format the background of the status to their respective colours. If I change the visual to table I can format it by clicking on the status. But when I change it to Matrix. It looses that functionality. How can I do this as the customer wants status group into Amber, Green and red. i would have used table but the customer don't want the status value to repeat in every role. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that in a matrix